# Hide a Form when a new Form is shown and show it again when the previous Form is closed

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I hide the Main Form when any of the Buttons that create and show another Form is clicked?
Closing the Form that has been opened from the Main Form, should cause the Main Form to show up again.

[image]

This is the code for the Click event of any of the buttons in the Main Form.

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    publisher p = new publisher();
    p.Show();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `this.Hide()` before showing the secondary form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a handler to the [FormClosed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed) event of the For you're about to show, [Hide()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.hide) the current Form, then, when the `FormClosed` event is raised, remove the handler and `Show()` the current Form again.

The `sender` object is the object instance that raised the event, so you can cast sender to Form - `(sender as Form)` - and remove the handler you added before. You can use this event handler to handle the `FormClosed` event of other Forms that need the same *treatment*.

If you inspect the `sender` object, you'll see that the Form instance is your `publisher` instance, `IsDisposed` is still `false` and `IsHandleCreated` is still `true`, so you can still *interact* with it.
For example, you could read the value returned by public (standard or *custom*) properties, in case it's needed.

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   publisher p = new publisher();
   p.FormClosed += OnFormClosed;
   this.Hide();
   p.Show();
}

private void OnFormClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (sender as Form).FormClosed -= OnFormClosed;
    this.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to hide a form:

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   publisher p = new publisher();
   p.Show();
   this.Hide();
 }
```